# Unable to change git (Enterprise) remote url without git trying to push un-tracked directory

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-enterprise

I need a repository hosted on GitLab to also be hosted on a GitHub Enterprise server. The server prevents files from over 100MB be uploaded.

I had a local Mongo database with two "prealloc" files that put aside 1GB each. I deleted the parent (data/) directory (now using MLab to host database), and stopped git tracking with `git rm data/`. I then do

`git remote set-url origin git@my-enterprise.github.git`

This sets the origin url to be the enterprise version. Then when I try and push, it aborts the push along with the message:

`remote: error: File data/journal/prealloc.0 is 1024.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

Even though the directory has gone. Its not in git's list of tracked files. Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+huge+file+history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even though the directory has gone. Its not in git's list of tracked files. Any ideas on what I might be missing?

- First of all, you still have it in your history.
- Second, verify that it is removed: `git rm -rf --cached data/`
  This will delete it from staging and you will have to commit the deletion.
- 3rd Clean up your repo with the BFG tool https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: cool, glad to help